# Invalid Selector Exception for CssSelector

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I am getting

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: An invalid or illegal selector was specified (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

when I am trying to exexute code in selenium webdriver to automate app in IE.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='javascript:XXX('ABCDEF');']")).click();
```

for this line of code.
HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:XXX('ABCDEF');">XXX</a>
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the two single quotes is creating the issue. Could you try this

```
"a[href=\"javascript:XXX('ABCDEF');\"]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `xpath` as:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'javascript:')][text()='XXX']")).click();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.